# Как передать jquery переменную в параметрах функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите товарищи, только начал осваивать jquery и не могу разобраться как передать переменную типа $('.переменная') в параметрах функции

```js
function slider(slid, slider, conteinerSlider){
  let widthSlid = $('.slid').outerWidth(true),
      widthSlider = $('.slider').outerWidth(),
      widthConteinerSlider = $('.conteinerSlider').outerWidth();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slid = "text";
$('.' + slid).text("World");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class = "text">Hello</p>
```